# gnuplot surface heat map from 2d array

Tags: data-visualization, gnuplot, visualization, surface

I'm trying to make a surface from my 2d data but failing, my data is like this in a txt file;

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 -0.04 -0.05 -0.04
0 -0.05 -0.07 -0.05
0 -0.04 -0.05 -0.04
0 0 0 0 0
```

is there way to make a colored, continious surface map using this data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What does "failing" mean? What have you tried? Please show code. What is the result? Please show graph or error message. Btw, shouldn't your data be a 5x5 matrix? But it is not.

Comment: You are right, I was a bit vogue. So the problem was I didn't know the right format for plotting, it should've been in X Y Z  format in columns to work. Thanks :))